# Will new Guid(byte[]) always produce a valid guid if the array is exactly 16 bytes and taken from a successfully received UDP socket?

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets, byte, guid

Trying to wrap my head around byte arrays that are produced by [Socket.ReceiveFrom(Byte[], EndPoint)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdfskwcy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and later used in [Guid Constructor (Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var data = new byte[16];
var length = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remoteEndpoint);
if(length == 16)
    var guid = new Guid(data);
```

Is it safe to assume that if `socket.ReceiveFrom(...)` did not produce an exception, `new Guid(data)` will never fail? Basically, is there ever a possibility that ReceiveFrom produces byte arrays that cannot be made into guids, without throwing an exception? Or do I have to validate the received byte array first?

Comment: There is not much magic behing the scenes, check out http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,49

Comment: It will not fail - but that doesn't mean you'll get a valid GUID. The `Guid` class doesn't do any validity checking. Guids aren't just random numbers - the bits have their meaning (for example, versioning).

Comment: @Luaan Good point. I guess this is actually two questions in one: will it fail, and will it procude a valid guid? For this particular case the produced guid will be compared to a dictionary of already existing valid guids generated by Guid.NewGuid(), and will be discarded if not equal.

Comment: Yup, in that case you're just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with where the data came from. How is `Guid` supposed to know the data came from a socket?

Any bytes are valid Guids, at least regarding the validation rules that `Guid` uses. This code will never throw:

```
if(length == 16)
    var guid = new Guid(data);
```

Guids do have some structure according to some Guid standard I believe but that structure is almost never being used by code. It has no practical impact. I do not know of a single system that would misbehave given badly structured guids.

Comment: Well, yeah, malformed GUIDs are more like a warning light - this obviously wasn't created by one of the proper GUID generating methods. GUIDs aren't really *parsed*, after all - they're "keys with no meaning".

Comment: Yes, I consider the MAC address method to generate a guid pointless and inferior. Random bytes would be just fine, maybe even more unique statistically because all those MAC address bytes are partially wasted.

Comment: The MAC address method is *actually* unique, though - provided you don't change the MAC from the one your NIC had to start with and noöne else does either (they *are* unique; until you change them). The rest of the GUID is also provably unique - though it does also mean that the maximum rate of GUID generation is limited, and the GUIDs are also quite predictable. Even then, the "real" random GUIDs still have a version number - the proper ones, that is.

Comment: @Luaan Honestly, I prefer the MAC address method, as it also allows me to identify the machine that created the `Guid`. (Which is especially useful when troubleshooting why all data coming from machine X keeps getting malformed, but no other machine does.)